# How to attain a state of Samadhi?

Tags: puranas, bhagavad-gita, upanishads, shiva-purana, devi-bhagavata-purana

How can one attain a higher state of consciousness or samadhi?

Comment: There are *infinite* ways to do that! What is your goal? and which samadhi?